# Forwarding Java HTTP Requests through another server

Tags: java, http, amazon-ec2, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have two AWS Instance I1 and I2 having Ip addresses as ip1 and ip2 respectively.What I want to achieve is:

- I want to hit a url from I1(using java httpclient) and want that request should go through I2 instance i.e to outside world it should appear that the request is coming from instance I2.

For Example :

I am executing the below-mentioned code from instance I1 :

```
class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

String url = "https://api.ipify.org?format=json",
       proxy = "ip2";
       Proxy p = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxy, 80));
 URL server = new URL(url);
Properties systemProperties = System.getProperties();
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)server.openConnection(p);
connection.connect();
String theString = IOUtils.toString(connection.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
 System.out.println(theString);
}
}
```

**The Output should be public Ip of instance I2**. But it is throwing the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient$1.run(HttpClient.java:515)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient$1.run(HttpClient.java:513)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.privilegedOpenServer(HttpClient.java:512)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:553)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1199)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:162)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$connect.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
        at com.exp.Test.main(Test.java:24)
```

I have googled for the above mentioned use case but was not able to find anything. Any help is appriciated.

Comment: I suppose that line 24 is `connection.connect();`?

Comment: Yes, it connection.connect(); I am not able to get your point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is fixed. 
Installed squid server on instance I2.